# Sorting/Filtering Multiple Columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Good evening. I am looking to see if it is possible to sort multiple columns in excel by selecting a value in Column A's filter.

Meaning: When I select Automobile in the drop down filter, Column B would show Cash and Column C would show paid.

What are the steps I would need to take in accomplishing this task.

Column A values: House Payment Automobile Payment Column B Values: Check Cash Credit Card No money Column C Values: Paid Unpaid

Comment: [This website](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal13.html) has multiple examples showing how to accomplish this.  Many thanks to @Máté Juhász for pointing out this site.

Comment: If your Data is already written you can use [Autofilter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-AutoFilter-to-filter-your-data-7d87d63e-ebd0-424b-8106-e2ab61133d92)

Comment: Thank you for all of the comments. I figured it out. I was looking to sort 3 columns based on a filter selection I would make in Column A without using a vlookup from column A for columns B & C.